# BASH - Shell Script - Sed command

Tags: bash, shell, file, sed, line

I'm trying to add text to a file with the sed command.
But nothing happens in the file. I use a variable to indicate the line I want to change.

```
j="1"
line1=`printf "\"desc_%s\": [\n" $2`
file="test"
sed -i "/$j/i \\$line1" $file
```

$2 is not empty.
What is the problem ?

Thank your advance

Comment: You never define `$file`. You never define `$line`. You define but never use `$line1`. You search for the string "1" when you might have meant line #1. You can save yourself a ton of trouble by trying to do it manually for one file before you write a script to do it generically.

Comment: I have edit my message. I have define variable but i have not error ...

Comment: Can you include an example file, what you get when you run your script on it, and what you expected to get?

Answer (score 1):

`sed -i` is a bit quirky. Try:

`sed -i'' "$j i ...etc`

-i expects a file suffix arg. And for *line* $j you just give the number. `/$j/` means, all lines having the string "1".

Answer (score 0):

```
$ txt=`echo -e 'hello wolrd!\nhi there!'`
$ sed '2iguys' <<<"$txt"
hello wolrd!
guys
hi there!
$ l=2;t=guys;sed "${l}i${t}" <<<"$txt"
hello wolrd!
guys
hi there!
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.